# Instance ID mismatch with dm-paperclip in a Sinatra + DataMapper app

Tags: ruby, paperclip, sinatra, datamapper

I'm trying to use dm-paperclip to handle uploads in my Sinatra app. It works fine with static values. However, when I try to use dynamic interpolation, a key part of the path that the uploaded file is saved in – the `:id` variable, which comes from dm-paperclip's interpolation – has one value at write time and a different value at read time.

In other words, I have this in my model:

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
  :url => '/system/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
  :path => "#{APP_ROOT}/public/system/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

# saves to path /my/root/public/system/attachments/217880/original/filename.png
```

It uploads and saves with no problem. However, when I do `@file.attachment.path` it shows something like:

```
/my/root/public/system/attachments/218298/original/filename.png
```

I can't find anything in dm-paperclip documentation or forums that talks about this. Someone please help! I've spent hours...

P.S. I tried switching to carrierwave-datamapper but that won't work either because it fails in a big way with to_json, which is critical for my app.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question but I encourage you to switch to carrierwave-datamapper - it's a much better solution to file uploads and what's even more important it's maintained.

Comment: Hi, Solnic. Did you see my P.S.? I'm also the one who submitted the issue on github about cw-dm failing on to_json and to_xml. That's a deal-breaker right now. Please let me know if you come up with a solution!

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't notice that 'P.S'. Anyhow, as you probably saw in the comment of your issue on GH it's a problem with carrierwave itself so we need to wait for a fix. I'll update the issue when the fix is ready.